# Positioning an Overlaying or floating View Above another view in Layout

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view, android-constraintlayout

In an Android application, I have a layout containing a `TextView` at the top and two elements beneath it: an `icon` and another `TextView`. The second TextView displays a numerical value that undergoes a counter animation using `ValueAnimator`.

Upon completion of this counter animation, in `doOnEnd` blcok, I aim to overlay an additional animation. The animation file is available with me.

Specifically, I seek guidance on positioning this overlay animation as follows:

1. The overlay animation should float above the numerical value displayed by the second TextView.
2. It must not disrupt the layout flow of the page, akin to absolute positioning in web development, ensuring that it remains visually distinct from the layout while anchored to the specified number.

How can I achieve this positioning and overlay of the animation in my Android application? Any insights or guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Note - I plan to use the constrain layout. However, if this is possible by using other layouts, I would be happy to use it.

Note - Need to consider text resize / font scaling while implementating.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can match the constraints of your animation to match the positioning of your second one.

```
    android:id="@+id/animation"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="second_text"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="second_text"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="second_text"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toTopStart="second_text"
```

and then use `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="float_value"` and `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="float_value"` to move the first text in the correct position. You might have to increase the top padding of the second text view.

Comment: I want the logic for positioning the animation view which will be anchor to number from second text view.